# One question per page on https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Tags: support, questions, pagination

When I visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions, I see exactly one question per page (tested over several pages), with normal paging controls. This only happens when I'm logged in.

I checked my account settings; the only thing that seems possibly relevant is my long list of ignored tags, but I do not have “hide ignored tags” turned on, and this is still arguably buglike even if that is the cause.

On the other hand, the next page loads quite snappily! :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this: In that page, I see 50 questions per page, as I select. Did you try changing the value (15, 30, 50) reported at the bottom of the page to the right of where the pager is shown?

Comment: Are any of the "per page" buttons selected? It's apparently possible to manually (accidentally or otherwise) get a pagesize of 1, and the pagesize is remembered on a per-user basis.

Comment: Yes, the only way I can reproduce it (and think of a scenario when this would happen) is by selecting 15 questions per page ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest&pagesize=15 ) trying to reload, but accidentally removing the last '5'. That gives you 1 question per page and is remembered. Might that be what has happened?

Comment: @Murelink please STOP those useless edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing one of the "per page" options fixed this. Thanks to Tim Stone.